# Ansible playbook for startup script with arguments

Tags: ansible

Is it possible in Ansible to write the startup script with input of arguments?

For example, in Unix, when we run it we can do:

`/etc/init.d/SCRIPT start|stop|restart`

Is it possible to do it in Ansible so it will read the input of  `start|stop|restart`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables into your playbook at runtime using the `-e` argument.  For example:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e mode=start
```

Given the above command line, inside the playbook, you can examine the `mode` variable:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: start something
      command: echo do you want to be starting something
      when: "mode|default('') == 'start'"
```

You can use as many `-e` arguments as you want, and you can include variables from a file rather than including them on the command line.  E.g., if you have a file `vars.yml`, you could run:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @vars.yml
```

---

So from one perspective, you would need to have three different tasks, each with a different `when` statement to handle the three `start`/`stop`/`restart` conditions.

But depending on what you're trying to do, there may be a simpler solution. If you're just trying to call the init script from a task, you could instead do this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: start something
      command: /etc/init.d/SCRIPT {{ mode }}
```

Comment: so I will have to write 3 statements  ?                                                                                       1) when: "mode|default('') = 'start'"                                                                                             2) when: "mode|default('') = 'stop'"                                                                                                3) when: "mode|default('') = 'restart'"                                                                                                is it right ?

Comment: is it exact statement with when ?                                                                                               I got error:   FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'mode|default('') = 'restart'' failed.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  Comparisons use `==`.